# Keyremap4macbook working intermittently?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard-layout

I have had a spill situation last year and I just found a link to remapping the shift key that was perpetually pressed. However now, it seems like something keeps overriding the key remapper and I have to constantly reload xml. What could be doing this? Can anyone help?